# How to check if string contains url anywhere in string using javascript and convert it to anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, regex

I have a `textarea` in which I am getting user's input data. But I need to know if there is any URL in textarea and convert it to anchor tag. For example:

**Textarea Data:**
`Hi I'm Abdul. My Website is https://website.com`

**After Anchor Tag:**
`Hi I'm Abdul. My Website is <a href="https://website.com">https://website.com</a>`

Currently my code is:

```
var status = $('#status').val();
var urlCheck = new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9]+://)?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@)?([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?");
        if(urlCheck.test(status)) {
        alert("url inside");
        console.log(urlCheck.exec(status)[0]);
}
```

This is my current code but I don't know how to replace url with anchor tag in that string.

Comment: textarea will only show plain text so it will not display the link as link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if i understand you correctly, but do you want to have it changed live or after the form was sent? If the latter, i would try something like this:

```
var urlCheck = new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9]+://)?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@)?([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?");
if(urlCheck.test(status)) {
alert("url inside");
console.log(urlCheck.exec(status)[0]);
// Here my possible solution (not tried out)
$('#status').val('<a href="http://'+urlCheck.exec(status)[0]+"' target='_blank'>the link</a>");
}
```

But this would also mean that you could/must check with a RegEX if the user entered http or not.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var status = $('#status').text();
var urlCheck = new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9]+://)?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@)?([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?");
if(urlCheck.test(status)) {
    alert("It has an URL!");
    console.log(urlCheck.exec(status)[0]);
}
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = status.replace(urlCheck.exec(status)[0],"<a href='"+urlCheck.exec(status)[0]+"'>"+urlCheck.exec(status)[0]+"</a>");
```

```html
<div id="status">Hi I'm Abdul. My Website is https://website.com</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

We can use the `html.replace()` to replace the url inside the tags we wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the JS [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function.

I set the following example with an input textarea and an output textarea for let you see the difference.

```js
function addUrl() {
  var status = $('#status').val();
  var urlCheck = /(([a-zA-Z0-9]+:\/\/)?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@)?([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:[0-9]+)?(\/.*)?)/;
  $('#output').val(status.replace(urlCheck, '<a href="$1">$1</a>'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="status">Input</label>
<textarea id="status" onChange="addUrl()"></textarea>
<br/>
<label for="output">Output</label>
<textarea id="output"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

use [linkifyHtml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/linkify-html) or [linkifyString](https://www.npmjs.com/package/linkify-string) : Linkify String Interface. Use linkify-string to replace links in plain-text strings with anchor tags.